# Unity Standalone Player Windows Desktop Platform- How to get path from file that is double click using Unity C#?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, path, double-click

My Windows desktop application made in Unity can read and play audio.wav but can't open it.
I want to double click a .WAV file and play it.
I have done myPlayWav(string path) function. 
And assigned to .wav file extension to call and run my application when is double click with the mouse. But:

How I get the audio file path when my application is open and run?
Do I need to include something? because there is no Unity function.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AtStart : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    void Start () 
    {
        string path;
        System.Run( path ?) ...
        StartCoroutine( myPlayWav ( path) );
    }

    //...
```

Is better to use Awake()?

Pease edit my English.

Comment: User vote me negative with no explanation. I wish to improve my question. any idea or advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Environment.CommandLine`.
This returns the raw (unformatted) string of the commandline. Then use `string.Split(' ')` to divide it into its individual args. At index 0 there should be your application. At index 1 the file you want to open and then at further indexes other arguments.

```
using System;

void Start ()
{
    string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split(' ');
    string path = args[1];
    StartCoroutine(myPlayWav(path));
}
```

**Note that if the application is NOT started by opening a file, args[1] will be empty.**

To prevent an `IndexOutOfRange` exception you could do this:

```
using System;

void Start ()
{
    string[] args = Environment.CommandLine.Split(' ');
    if (args.Length < 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("There is no file that is trying to be opened!");
        return;
    }
    string path = args[1];
    StartCoroutine(myPlayWav(path));
}
```

Comment: Thx! Since is a question for "Unity" users,can you add more information and expand the section about using System.Environment? I try to use  System.Environment.CommandLineArgs but was not possible by default. Probably my question was negative because there are a lot of similar questions but not for Unity users. Or edit my Eng.

Comment: @SoaringCode Yeah I can try tomorrow. Can you just further specify what you mean by "not possible by default"? Does it work like this or does it cause an error?

Comment: Err: `System.Environment' is a type not a namespace. A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces. Looks like CommandLineArgs() do not exist. Can be GetCommandLineArgs() instead?

Comment: @SoaringCode You can try it, `System.Environment.CommandLineArgs` is what I found on a unity forum for the same question.

Comment: Was not possible to use System.Environment.CommandLine() and System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() do not returns the correct file path. The only way it works in Unity for Windows is to include system on top: using System; and then Environment.CommandLine; but without "()" or directly System.Environment.CommandLine;

Comment: And also cannot implicitly convert Environment.CommandLine type `string' to args type `string[]' array.

Comment: @SoaringCode Thats because that is the unformatted command line as a string. Use `string.Split(' ')` to get the individual arguments.

Comment: Ok! and it returns at index 1 .  Not at index 0

Comment: @SoaringCode Look I can't do everything for you. `Environment.CommandLine` returns the **whole commandline**, meaning also the name of the application. Further starting arguments are at the further indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123404/discussion-between-soaring-code-and-ian-h).